# Windows Phone 7 Spell Check on textboxes

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I implement the spell check feature for my large text boxes for my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally there is no spell check. If you are talking about generalized suggestions, you can get those by using a specific SIP (Software Input Panel) - **Text**.

Official documentation: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426929%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

You will have to manually specify the InputScope:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputScope>
        <InputScope>
            <InputScopeName NameValue="Text"/>
        </InputScope>
    </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: That is awesome!  That is just what I wanted.